# how to set Details page to be default view when opening a record in Lightning UI

Tags: lightning

Is there way to land on Details tab by default when viewing a record in Lightning UI ?[image: Details Tab in lightning UI]

Comment: believe its all early days and there's not much customisations allowed with the lightning experience setup / user interface..

Comment: As of today, there is no option to do it.

Comment: Srikanth/Vamsi - Any luck with this ? ie open Details tab by default when opening a url from VF page ..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way to make your Details tab as default landing tab. Go to your Detail record page-->Click on the Setup button at the top right corner of the page--> and click Edit page. It should take to the Lightning Edit page.

Click on Related or Details Tab. On the right side column you will see a way to make "**Details**" as default tab. Once the changes are made, hit save and activate it to all your users. Attached is the image.

[image: Click on Setup]

[image: Click on tabs]

Comment: Where in metadata this configuration saved? Need to spread this configuration via CI among multiple development orgs and sandboxes

Comment: I am not quite aware of that, you probably want to check below link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm

Comment: There are in flexipages metadata. It is also called Lightning record pages from salesforce UI.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but,

To do this in metadata you will need to have:

```
<componentInstanceProperties>
 <name>active</name>
 <value>true</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
```

In the flexipage-meta.xml, inside the componentInstances for the tab you want (and to change the current default tabs value to false).